Switchable Grey Water system for a retrofit install?
I am trying to design and install a code compliant residential grey-water system, but the person I am working for wishes to have 2 valves installed so that the system can be routed back to the standard waste management system if needed.  The current system I am installing on has its own vent, so if I isolate the section from the rest of the DWV system I wont evacuate the P-trap :).
I am a novice to home plumbing, but not to fluid mechanics and plumbing design, so I agreed to this, but I have quickly realized I am a bit over my head regarding standard parts.  There are no off-the-shelf full-way valves in ABS (which the old system is made from) in my area.  I am starting to realize that this is perhaps flow control is a non-standard part of most home plumber's experience.  Is there any robust options that I have for making the system switchable that don't involve valves?
One things I was thinking about was some kind of flexible mechanical connector with removable caps that could be left in the crawl space and easily switched out by someone modestly handy...  This would be an acceptable solution for me, but the flexible mechanical connectors I see at the store appear to have a lip, so I would have difficulty with assembly.
